# How to add a button to a collectionview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Currently I have a `collectionview` with a cell which loads images from `library`.I wish to add a cell with a button before that to open the `camera`.How can I do this??

```
import UIKit
import Photos
import MobileCoreServices
private let reuseIdentifier = "PhotoCell"
class AddPhotoViewController: UIViewController , UIImagePickerControllerDelegate ,UINavigationControllerDelegate ,UICollectionViewDataSource ,UICollectionViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var photoAlbum: UICollectionView!

    var TakenImage : UIImageView!
    var selectedImage : UIImage!
    var pickedImage : UIImage!
    var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection!
    var photosAsset: PHFetchResult!
    var assetThumbnailSize: CGSize!
    let imagePicker: UIImagePickerController! = UIImagePickerController()
    var cameraon : Bool = false
    var index : [NSIndexPath]!

    var note : String!
    var noteAlreadyEntered = false
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let collection:PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(.SmartAlbum, subtype: .SmartAlbumUserLibrary, options: nil)

        var i = 0
        repeat
        {
            if let first_Obj:AnyObject = collection.objectAtIndex(i)
            {
                self.assetCollection = first_Obj as! PHAssetCollection
            }
            i++
        }while( i < collection.count)



        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func takePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {

        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.sourceType = .Camera
        presentViewController(picker, animated: true,completion : nil)
        save(TakenImage.image!)


    }
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
    {

        TakenImage.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage ; dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil )

    }
    @IBAction func save(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(TakenImage.image!, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
    }
    func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo:UnsafePointer<Void>)
    {
        if error == nil {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else
        {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }


        override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        if let layout = self.photoAlbum!.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
            let cellSize = layout.itemSize

            self.assetThumbnailSize = CGSizeMake(cellSize.width, cellSize.height)
        }

        //fetch the photos from collection
        self.photosAsset = PHAsset.fetchAssetsInAssetCollection(self.assetCollection, options: nil)

        self.photoAlbum!.reloadData()


    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate

    /*
    // Uncomment this method to specify if the specified item should be selected
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
    }
    */


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        if (segue.identifier == "savePhoto")
        {
            if let controller : NoteDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? NoteDetailViewController
            {
                controller.takinPhoto = true
             //   controller.imageView2.image = TakenImage.image
                if(noteAlreadyEntered == true)
                {
                    controller.content = note
                    controller.imageView.image = TakenImage.image
                }
                else
                {
                    controller.imageView2.image = TakenImage.image
                }

            }
        }
           if (segue.identifier == "saveSelected")
        {


            let cell = sender as! PhotoAlbumCollectionViewCell
            let indexPath = photoAlbum.indexPathForCell(cell)
            let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as! NoteDetailViewController
            destVC.asset = self.photosAsset[indexPath!.item] as! PHAsset

            destVC.flag = true
            if(noteAlreadyEntered == true)
            {
                destVC.content = note
            }

        }



    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
    }



    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
    {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        var count: Int = 0

        if(self.photosAsset != nil){
            count = self.photosAsset.count
        }
        print("\(self.photosAsset.count)")
        return count + 1
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell: PhotoAlbumCollectionViewCell = photoAlbum.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("PhotoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotoAlbumCollectionViewCell

        //Modify the cell
        let asset: PHAsset = self.photosAsset[indexPath.item] as! PHAsset

        PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: self.assetThumbnailSize, contentMode: .AspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: {(result, info)in
            if let image = result {
                cell.setThumbnailImage(image)
            }
        })

        return cell
    }



    func collectionView(collectinView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 4
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldShowMenuForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, performAction action: Selector, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withSender sender: AnyObject?) {

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Comment: Is your imageView in collection view's cell acquiring cell's size completely, if yes then why don't you use collection view's delegate method - didSelectRowAtIndexPath, without adding button which would do same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using custom class for collectionview cell and have already added camera image to first index of your array as you want to add option to open camera before your images. This is the easist way to do this.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Identifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourCustomcell

cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: arryImage[indexPath.item] as String)

return cell
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
   if indexPath.item == 0 {
       //Code to open camera
   }else{

   }        
}
```

This is the simplest way to achieve what you want. If you dont want to add camera image to your array of images, then just increase the array count by 1 in numberOfItemsInSection method and make following changes in cellForItemAtIndexPath method

```
if indexPath.item == 0 {
           cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "CameraImage")
}else{
           cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: arryImage[(indexPath.item)-1] as String)
}
```

didSelectItemAtIndexPath method will remain same. If you want the opencamera function at the end then make changes accordingly.

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You are already passing one more count in the `numberOfItemInSection` method. So just change your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` like this

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: PhotoAlbumCollectionViewCell = photoAlbum.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("PhotoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotoAlbumCollectionViewCell
    if (indexPath.item == 0) {
         let btn = UIButton(frame: cell.contentView.bounds) //Set your frame that you want
         btn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "add"), forState: .Normal)
         btn.addTarget(self, action: #Selector(addNewImage(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
         cell.contentView.addSubview(btn)
    }
    else {
        //Modify the cell
        let asset: PHAsset = self.photosAsset[indexPath.item-1] as! PHAsset
        PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: self.assetThumbnailSize, contentMode: .AspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: {(result, info)in
             if let image = result {
                 cell.setThumbnailImage(image)
             }
         })
     }
     return cell
}
```

Now just add this `addNewImage` method in your `ViewController` like this

```
func addNewImage(sender: UIButton) {
     //Add the code of ImagePicker
}
```

To solve your `segue` problem you need to override `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` method in your `ViewController`

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if (identifier == "saveSelected")
    {
        let cell = sender as! PhotoAlbumCollectionViewCell
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            self.addNewImage(UIButton()) // To Open Camera
            return false //To stop perform Segue.
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: I have added an imageview to my collectionview cell alredy.Would that be an issue?

Comment: No there is no problem with that.

Comment: code is the same.In my storyboard i've added an imageview to the cell

Comment: Then what is problem? Also you need to change your `didSelect` for `indexPath.item != 0` action

Comment: I have added a segue from the cell to another viewcontroller NoteDetailViewController.How can I pass the image taken with this new buttton to NoteDetailViewController. I mean how can I do this in didSelect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117152/discussion-between-nirav-and-vineeth-krishnan).

Comment: Check my edited answer, you need to override `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` method in your `ViewController`.